# how to add the footer in the tcpdf library

Tags: pdf, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to create the pdf and i want to add the copyright text in the footer but this footer text is showing above the header . Here is the code

```
$this->MultiCell(0, 10, $wpptopdfopts['pdf_footer'], 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create class extending TCPDF class:

```
    class YourPdfGenerator extends TCPDF {}
```

2.Overwrite footer method with your data:

```
public function Footer() {
    [...]
    $pagenumtxt = $this->l['w_page'] . ' ' . $this->getAliasNumPage() . ' / ' . $this->getAliasNbPages();
    $this->SetDrawColor(128, 128, 128);
    $this->Line(10, 264, 200, 264);
    $this->SetFont('myfont', '', 6);
    $this->SetTextColor(80, 80, 80);
    $this->SetXY(10, -32);
    $this->MultiCell(190, 10, $this->locale($this->lang->trans('report_label_offer_policy')), 0, 'L');
    $this->SetFont('myfont', '', 8);
    $this->SetXY(10, -14);
    $this->Cell(192, 10, $this->locale($date_now), 0, 0, 'L');
    $this->SetXY(10, -14);
    $this->Cell(190, 10, $pagenumtxt, 0, 0, 'R');
  }
```

3.Enjoy